# Explain what Vue operator this is and what it does <%= %>

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, operators

Could anyone give a clear and easy to follow explanation of the following operator:

```
<%= %>
```

To give you some context:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted'

Vue.use(Toasted, <%= serialize(options.toastOptions) %>)
```

Comment: That's not a JavaScript operator. It's part of the Vue framework.

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: @Barmar: Are you sure?  It looks like ASP.NET MVC template syntax to me.  The Vue docs don't seem to have anything like this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't actually know Vue or ASP.NET. I know lots of template systems use that syntax, I assumed it was Vue since he gave that tag.

Comment: @Barmar: So you are not sure if this operator belongs to Vue or Javascript?

Comment: I know it's not JavaScript. It's part of a template system built on top of JavaScript.

Comment: This looks like Elixir/Phoenix templating syntax https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.4/templates.html , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963201/phoenix-render-template-that-has-assigns-values-inside-a-template